# How can I TryParse() a string inputted by the user?

Tags: c#, string, input, console, double

I have a C# program which takes a user input of a number (`r.length = Console.ReadLine();`), then calls `Double.Parse(r.length);`. However, I would like to use `TryParse();`, which returns `false` is it fails. So I have an `if...else` statement that outputs a message if there is an error. The conditional statement is as follows: `if(Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, out r.length));`. But converting a `method group` to a `string` is not allowed.

*EDIT: As requested, here is a sample program demonstrating my problem:*

```
using System;

namespace sample
{
    class sample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double my_number;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            if(Double.TryParse(Console.WriteLine, out my_number))
            {}
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Expected number.");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string' (CS1503)`

So how can I work around this?

Comment: Can you please show short but complete program demonstrating your problem?

Comment: You need to read from console to a variable, so you can try and test things with it. It will also help you debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out my_number))
   Console.WriteLine("not a double.");
```

Comment: `r.length` should be `my_number` with the example,  is hard to tell what r is in the description

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer, I answered before the OP made the edits to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `Console.WriteLine` writes the console. You need to use [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method to read input string.
2. `Console` does not have `GetKey` method. Sounds like you need [`ReadKey` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx).

   ```
   double my_number;

   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
   if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out my_number))
   {

   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Error: Expected number.");
   }
   Console.ReadKey();
   ```